# Использование Interop в C# для работы с Access

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, office-interop

Как обойти все таблицы игнорируя системные таблицы?

Я придумал только такой костыль:

```
 foreach (TableDef tableDef in db.TableDefs)
            {
                if (!tableDef.Name.Contains("Sys")&&!tableDef.Name.Contains("~"))
                {

                }
            }
```

Нашел такое перечисление, но не понял как с помощью него отбирать нужные мне таблицы:

TableDefAttributeEnum

Я пытался сравнивать с атрибуты на конкретной таблице, но не получил нужного результата.

Comment: нормальный костыль. Если ваша задача перебрать, ВСЕ таблицы, но исключить системные для MS Access.

Comment: @3per проблема в том, что он на 100% не решает задачу. Юзер может назвать свою таблицу так что она будет содержать эти сочетания и тогда ее я упущу. Конечно можно заложить логику, но я думаю что должно быть готовое решение

Comment: А каким способом происходит соединение с БД? для ADOX вот нашёл способ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa165325(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: @3per, интеропт.